# compilation error in function returning a struct in C

Tags: c

I keep getting this compilation error:

> error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘&’ token

on the marked line below:

```
//128 bit vector struct (4 integers)
typedef struct {
  int w, x, y, z;
} iVector4;

iVector4 SSEadd(iVector4 &v1, iVector4 &v2)  // <-- this line
{
  iVector4 vr;
  asm
  {
    MOV EAX v1
    MOV EBX v2
    //
    MOVUPS XMM0, [EAX]
    MOVUPS XMM1, [EBX]
    //
    PADDD XMM0 XMM1
    MOVUPS [rv]
  }
  return rv;
}
```

I really can't see what's wrong: What seems to be the problem?

EDIT:

Hi thanks for all the responses.

I'm using gcc as a compiler, and I realize that the assembly code that I had provided was also incorrect.I was wondering if its best to use the built_in functions from -msse/-msse2.

Also, what's the most efficient way to load and extract values from a vector such as v4si?

I'm finding that loading and extracting from the vector  is a costly ooperation.

When you say sse intrinsics, what exactly did you mean?

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: My C is a bit rusty. Does C even have references?

Answer (score 7):

C does not have references. You need to compile as C++ for those.

Comment: Blindingly obvious, but I didn't see it.

Answer (score 4):

C doesn't have references. You should use a pointer instead, or use C++.

```
iVector4 SSEadd(iVector4 *v1, iVector4 *v2)
```

Now the next question - can you return objects in C? My C is rusty. If that's the not case, you'd need:

```
void  SSEadd(iVector4 *v1, iVector4 *v2, iVector4 *vOut)
```

EDIT: As Justin pointed out, it is possible, so you don't need to go that route. You still could though - depending on the circumstances, it could be more performant.

Comment: Next time, ysap, next time :)

Comment: You can return structures, yes. They get placed on the stack.

Comment: I assume they just do a plain member-by-member copy? Well, the second part is moot then. Thanks Justin! (That said, depending on the circumstances, taking a `vOut` pointer can still be faster, and this seems like a core function.) While we're at it - does SSE have alignment requirements for its 128-bit registers like VMX does?

Answer (score 1):

I think your function definition should actually be:

`iVector4 SSEadd(iVector4 *v1, iVector4 *v2);`

Answer (score 1):

You also might want to consider using SSE intrinsics instead of what it looks like you're doing.